# Apache Reverse proxy to fight DNS propagation

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

I have been following this [tutorial](https://deliciousbrains.com/fighting-dns-propagation-reverse-proxy/) to set up a reverse proxy. I have moved some sites to a new server, and changing the DNS for a lot of alias domains is going to take a while. To minimize issues, I want to redirect all traffic to the new location with a reverse proxy.

It does work, but I get a default page on the new server while configuration is exactly the same and editing my hosts file does work.

This is the config that I'm using:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias *.domain.com
        ServerAlias domain2.com *.domain2.com
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/proxy-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/proxy-access.log combined
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPass / http://x.x.x.x/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://x.x.x.x/
        
</VirtualHost>
```

Does it has something to do with the fact that I use http://ip_adress/ for the ProxyPass condition?

Comment: I'd think that ProxyPass with an IP address simply does not pass the required Host header

Comment: Maybe https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost would do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setup requires that the original Host: header be passed onward from your proxy to the new origin server.

This is done with [`ProxyPreserveHost`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost):

```
    ProxyPreserveHost On
```